# Get IEnumerable<T> in generic method based on specific property value

Tags: c#, generics

I have no idea how to get `IEnumerable<T>` in generic method based on specific property value. Here's my code:

```
public List<T> ReadByProperty<T>(string propName, object propValue)
    where T : class
{
    return base.repository.Query<T>().AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => x.GetType()
                      .GetProperty(propName)
                      .GetValue(x, null) == propValue)
               .ToList();
}
```

Here's the similar code in non generic method:

```
return base.repository.Query<Models.Role>().Where(w => w.UserId == 2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build an expression manually and pass that to `Where`:

```
var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
var propExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, propName);
var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(propExpr, Expression.Constant(propValue));
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eqExpr, paramExpr);

return base.repository.Query<T>()
           .Where(predicate).ToList();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the `.AsEnumerable()` to prevent the full set of `T` objects being pulled back?

Comment: @derodevil - You need to remove the call to `AsEnumerable`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Yes, you are correct, thanks. It won't even compile with that there.

Comment: @derodevil - What arguments are you passing to `ReadByProperty`? The type of `propValue` must match the type of the property given by `propName`.